# How to share application link using Xamarin Essentials Share to other users and open application once they click?

Tags: xamarin.forms, share, xamarin.essentials

Is there a way to share application page URI using Xamarin Essentials Share and when other user clicks on same shared URI it should open application if it's installed? Do I need to use App links? The issue is I don't have website and cannot use app links. Any hints would be helpful.

Comment: refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/deep-linking

Comment: I already gone through it, as I mentioned I don't have website and this document doesn't give much details for IOS.

Comment: I see that you have used deep linking and seem to have encountered new problems.

Answer (score 1):

For Android, if your targetted app support [Deep Linking](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking) then you can open/share formatted link of that app.

For example of Whatsapp, you can create link following this [format](https://faq.whatsapp.com/iphone/how-to-link-to-whatsapp-from-a-different-app/?lang=en)

So you just need to share the formatted link using Xamarin.Essentials Share and then you will be redirected to that app.

Comment: It's actually my own application link, I want to share a page of my application via WhatsApp or email and when user clicks it they will be navigate to my application if is installed. My application doesn't have deep linking functionality in place, we cannot do without implementing deep linking?

Comment: No, you can't. You need to add Deep Linking to your app

Comment: But I don't have website to host the application file for IOS

Comment: @Zeeshanshaikh this is the way of doing this. You can spin up a quick and simple website on Netlify if it's the only blocker.

Comment: is it only required to verify domain or the same link path should work on website as well?